# How to control NAS using iphone as a remote control?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way or code available to control TV connected to NAS using iphone as a remote control?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Blackberry and a D-Link DNS 323, but the idea should be the same for you: install SSH on your NAS, configure your network/router to forward the SH port to the NAS, and use an SSH client on the phone (I used midpSSH).

I guess that if you want a nice GUI, you can build one and map buttons to commands sent over SSH.

Comment: Thanks Traveling Tech Guy. I would really help me, I will search over this solution. Thanks for your response. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

You could write an iPhone app to do that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, But is there any available app or code similar to that app that can help me or provide some guidance?

Comment: I think a minimum amount of information would include something about *which* NAS you have in mind. At the moment it looks like you want someone to say 'Yes, here's the code (you don't have to do anything'

Comment: Hi , Thanks. I understood the thing. I don't want anyone to say 'Yes, here's the code (you don't have to do anything'). I just asked to guide if anyone has done such thing before. I just asked for some guidance, if anyone can help it.
Thanks for your response.